# How can I convert a string(1,234) into a number(1234) using script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are several ways to convert a string into an integer, when the string ex:"1,234",

```
parseInt("1,234")
```

is converted into number the o/p : will be 1. Is there any way to get the number as 1234 when i enter string "1,234". Please suggest me to get the number. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace `,` with nothing, then `parseInt`

Comment: `parseInt( '1,234'.replace(/,/g, '') )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**with variable**

```
var tempnum="1,234";
parseInt(tempnum.replace(/,/g,""));
```

**without variable**

```
parseInt("1,234".replace(/,/g,""));
```

reference [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: Why a variable? You also need to replace all commas, not just one.

Answer (score 5):

I would strip out all commas from the given string.

```
parseInt("1,234".replace(/,/g,""),10);
```

Note that the `/,/g` is required (as opposed to `","` since

```
"1,234,567".replace(",","") == "1234,567";
"1,234,567".replace(/,/g,"") == "1234567";
```

Note that `","` will only replace the *first* instance of `,` while `/,/g` will replace all instances.

Comment: Don't use `parseInt` without the radix argument.

Comment: @Tomalak Right.  Thanks for catching that!

Comment: can I use the same for Number()

Comment: You can use `parseInt` without the radix in ECMAScript 5 since the default radix is 10, but it's a good idea to always pass the parameter just in-case.

Comment: @JoeSimmons Whether or not the OP uses the radix argument or not depends on whether he thinks users would input octal/hex values (instead of numbers with a leading 0).

Comment: @user2837416 I would highly appreciate it if you clicked the check mark next to the score on this question if you found it useful.

Comment: There are languages where ',' is used as the decimal place and '.' as the thousands separator, so an on–screen hint for number format (and not a "placeholder") should be included if the value is user input.

Comment: That's good an all, but all the solutions out here fall short when trying to parse numbers in a different locales. For example: "1 234 234,456". I'd suggest using a library like this one if trying to handle other formats of the world matters to you. http://numeraljs.com/

Answer (score 1):

check this out

```
var num = '1,234';
num = num.replace(/,/g, '');
num = parseInt(num, 10);
```

Comment: You need to replace all commas, not just one.